# How to store multiple checkbox value into one database filed

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm developing a system in which im asking user to mark as checked products which customer whats to buy. i have created this product table in details and created a list of checkboxes dynamically based upon entry made in product table. below is my codes to created check boxes.

```
    $query_parent4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product") or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());
    <div class="col-sm-8 icheck ">
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent4)): ?>
    <div class="square-blue single-row">
    <div class="checkbox" >
    <input  name="product[]" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" type="checkbox"><label> <?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
```

Now i want store all the selected checkbox value in a filed which i have created in customer table with name of 'Product' like given below

Product : 1:2:3:4:5

im using below mention code to achieve this task but not getting success on this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fac=$_POST['product'];
    $fac1=implode(":",$fac);

    $sql=mysql_query("update hotel_info set product='$fac1' where custid=$custid");

}
?>
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: you can store it with comma, means comma separated values..

Comment: what value return by $_POST['product'];. is it array or something else.

Comment: Bad idea. That should be 5 rows in a  new table

Comment: I know it's outside the scope of this question, but you may want to look at redesigning your database. A more common practice would be to have an extra table, lets call it 'customer_product', which would have foreign keys (custid,product_id)

Comment: use jQuery and get all selected checkbox value in one variable and after get all checkbox value assign that variable to some hidden field and store that hidden field ......

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fac=$_POST['product'];


foreach($fac as $fac1)
        {
           $sql=mysql_query("update hotel_info set product='$fac1' where custid=$custid");

        }        
}
?>
```

Here, `$fac` is returning an `array` so you can not use it directly.

Comment: That doesn't make sense unless he has somehow stored multiple copies of the same customer in his database, and then your query would still update all of them at the same time with the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad idea to store multiple values to a single column.
I would suggest, go for a new table mapping each product vs customer(as its a many to many relationship).

Something like this:

```
Customer: id, name<br>
Product: id, name, price<br>
Customer_Product(or call it Order):id, customer_id, product_id, qty, due etc.
```

This would make table structures normalized.